# Javascript - handle mouse dragging event

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener

I'm new to JavaScript and I created a coloring grid.

It should be possible to draw images by dragging the mouse, but that is not happening. Whenever a cell is clicked, the dragging starts. All cells that the mouse moves over should be activated and colored with the selected color.

When the mouse is released, dragging stops and the cells are no longer activated by mouse movement.
[coloring grid](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lhfxf.png)

This is my code, but I can do it only for mouse clicked:

```
var td = document.querySelectorAll('#my-table td');
td.forEach(e => e.addEventListener("click", function() {
    if(this.style.backgroundColor =="" || this.style.backgroundColor =="white"){
    this.style.backgroundColor = selectedColor;
    }
    else{
        this.style.backgroundColor = "white";
    }
}));
```

Comment: Please show us your failed attempt(s). That said you certainly didn't start learning JS with the easiest of tasks :-)

Answer (score 0):

Try to use mousemove and mouseup/mousedown events to check mouse's status in Javascript.

So first check mousedown event in grid and then check mousemove.

When happen mouseup event, you could check the grid and do action.

Reference 
[mousemove](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/mousemove_event)
[mouseup/mousedown](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/mousedown_event)

Comment: I tried to use mousedown and mouseup events but I don't know how could I tell him to color the selected cell. because  this.style.backgroundColor = selectedColor;
is the cell that the mouseon only.
How could I save all the selected table cells to color it?

Comment: Whenever cells mouse over, you could apply color style immediately for each individual cells. This is idea.

Comment: So try to attach addEventListener("mouseover", function( event ) for each cell and do actions.

Comment: You could find similar sample here. http://prntscr.com/qr8qmj

Answer (score 0):

I solved it.

```
var isClicked = false;

window.addEventListener('mousedown', e => {

  isClicked = true;
});


window.addEventListener('mouseup', e => {
  if (isClicked === true) {
    isClicked = false;
  }
});
//do{
td.forEach(e => e.addEventListener("mousemove", function() {
    // Here, `this` refers to the element the event was hooked on
if (isClicked === true) {
    this.style.backgroundColor = selectedColor;
}

}));
td.forEach(e => e.addEventListener("click", function() {
    // Here, `this` refers to the element the event was hooked on

    if(this.style.backgroundColor =="" || this.style.backgroundColor =="white"){
    this.style.backgroundColor = selectedColor;
    }
    else{
        this.style.backgroundColor = "white";
    }

}));
```